# Spring boot 3.1.6 supported Java & Tomcat version

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat10

I'm running **Tomcat:10.1-jdk17-corretto** in Docker with Spring Boot 3.0.5. Everything is operating smoothly.

Upgrading Spring Boot from 3.0.5 to 3.1.6 has resulted in the following difficulties. I think the most recent version of Spring Boot may not support Tomcat or Java 17. However, the Docker Hub does not have the most recent Tomcat JDK17 correctto.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue and which Java and Tomcat versions Spring Boot supports.

**Debug logs updated**

````
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean.register(DynamicRegistrationBean.java:122) ~[spring-boot-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236) ~[spring-boot-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:192) ~[spring-boot-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
    ... 49 more
 13-Dec-2023 17:42:00.709 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/samplespring.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1950)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:777)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1657)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:310)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/documentprocessor]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)```
````

Comment: Why do you want to use a full fledged tomcat when spring boot has it embedded? Also, if you want to stick with it, change the log level to debug, the current log you are using is not helpful. Another thing is to prepare a small reproducible sample.

Comment: Thanks, Sure I will do a small reproducible sample. Could you please let me know which Tomcat and Java versions Spring Boot supports?

Comment: Go to [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat) on the maven repo click on the spring boot version you are using, scroll down. There is a list of dependencies and tomcat ones are there.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - Debug logs updated. Please check and let me know.

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward "Error deploying web application archive" you likely are generating the war file in a wrong way, deploying the wrong way, or missing something on it that is causing the error. Without knowing what you are doing, hard to tell.